# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error while embeding youtube video

Tags: php, youtube, embed

here is my embed code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/x9pRNcoP1EU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

here is the error in console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to add the following at the top of php page - without success

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

how to solve this?

Comment: I think they have done some CORS policy changes. Same issue I'm also facing.

Answer (score 6):

As @david-vielhuber said in the comments, this isn't related to your domain but to the CORS policy on "**googleads.g.doubleclick.net**". There is nothing you can do beyond changing the way you embed YouTube videos.

[image: example of CORS Policy Error: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]

[CORS Policy Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htaccess:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: No, Google has to add this to they domain doubleclick.net. This has nothing to do with the websites CORS policy, where the iframe is embedded.