# Blocked by CORS policy error by embedding YouTube video

Tags: youtube-api

When embedding a YouTube video:
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/QL4bz3QXWEo.

And I open the devtools, it results to the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id' from origin 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there something that can be done to fix it, or is it related to the CORS policy on "googleads.g.doubleclick.net"? If the latter is true, are there any plans to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [youtube embeded video error NO ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480196/youtube-embeded-video-error-no-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: @DaImTo
Thanks for your reply, but it did not work.

If I look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64973469/no-access-control-allow-origin-error-while-embeding-youtube-video
It says it's related to the CORS policy on "googleads.g.doubleclick.net"

Are there any plans to fix it?